# Set equal height columns using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know a solution to create equal height columns using `display:table` like:

```
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.col{
    display: table-cell; 
}
```

but my case is a bit different, since I am using flexbox and row class has `display:flex`:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  display: ms-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

and all cols have `.large-4` class:

```
.large-4 {
   width: 25%;
   max-width: 25%;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}
```

I can't use `flex:1` for `.large-4` as well because it varies in different viewport. 
here is a snippet of html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="author">
      <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-title">Title</h1>
        <p class="grey-text mgb-05">2012-09-05, by Basir Payenda</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae quas eligendi id est iste
          distinctio
          optio vel aliquam provident, ipsa reprehenderit in corrupti quia ratione quisquam amet veniam totam
          veritatis.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="author">
      <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-title">Title</h1>
        <p class="grey-text mgb-0">2012-09-05, by Basir Payenda</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="author">
      <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-title">Title</h1>
        <p class="grey-text mgb-05">2012-09-05, by Basir Payenda</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae quas eligendi id est iste
          distinctio.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

code-pen link can be found [here](https://codepen.io/basirpayenda/pen/ZEGXmBE)! how to I acheive equal height columns using flexbox? or any other better solution. thanks

Comment: Hi, I was answering your carousel question but you deleted it!

Comment: ohh great @ariel, I thought the community didn't welcome it. I am going to undo it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577870/how-to-add-smooth-transition-between-first-and-last-slide-of-a-carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `display: flex` to the `.large-4` element:

```
.large-4 {
   width: 25%;
   max-width: 25%;
   flex: 0 0 30%;
   display: flex;
}
```

You'll notice when you inspect your elements using the inspector tool, `large-4` elements are actually all the same height. It's the content inside that is not. So by making the parent element flex, it will make the children elements fill the space.

Comment: Or just add the `d-flex` class if they're using Bootstrap 4...

Comment: That works as well, but they didn't have bootstrap listed as a tag so I went with the ol' property instead :)

Comment: If you set the flex-basis to 30% (Specifies the initial size of the flex item) - no meaning her for "width: 25%" value.

Answer (score 0):

You already have equal-height columns, but inside them is a container that is contracting to its content. Expand that container.

```
.card {
    height: 100%;
}
```