# Fix dots bug to indicate the slides in carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am almost done with my ideal carousel except that I tried to add dots indicating slides which doesn't works as expected, `.active` class in `.dot` behaves weird, to see here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/basirpayenda/pen/mdJqBaR?editors=0010).

Here is the HTML I used:

```
<div class="carousel-container">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-left" id="prevBtn"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" id="nextBtn"></i>
    <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-158&q=80" class="firstSlide" alt="">
        ...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dots">
    <span class="dot active"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

and here is the JavaScript I used:

```
/* carousel */
const carousel_slide = document.querySelector(".carousel-slide");
const carousel_images = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-slide img");

const dots = document.querySelector(".dots");
const dot = document.querySelectorAll(".dot");

const prev_btn = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
const next_btn = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");

// counter
let counter = 0;
let size = carousel_images[0].clientWidth;

carousel_slide.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "afterbegin",
  carousel_images[carousel_images.length - 1].outerHTML
);
carousel_slide.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", carousel_images[0].outerHTML);
carousel_slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-size * 1}px)`;

// carousel_slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-size * counter}px)`;

next_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (counter >= carousel_images.length) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      counter = 0;
      dot[counter].classList.add("active");
      carousel_slide.style.transition = "none";
      carousel_slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-size}px)`;
    }, 300);
  } else {
    carousel_slide.style.transition = "all 0.3s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    for (i = 0; i < dot.length; i++) {
      dot[i].className = dot[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    dot[counter].classList.add("active");
    carousel_slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-size * (counter + 1)}px)`;
  }
});

prev_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (counter < 0) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      counter = carousel_images.length - 1;
      carousel_slide.style.transition = "none";
      carousel_slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-size * (counter + 1)}px)`;
    }, 300);
  } else {
    carousel_slide.style.transition = "all 0.3s ease-in-out";
    counter--;
    for (i = 0; i < dot.length; i++) {
      dot[i].className = dot[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    dot[counter].classList.add("active");
    carousel_slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-size * (counter + 1)}px)`;
  }
});
```

and I was unable to add a click event on dots to take me to its respective slide in carousel. Thank you for reading and helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looked into your codepen details I have found the issue with your carousel while triggering the next and the previous button. Edit this answer with transition effect helping from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577870...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577870/how-to-add-smooth-transition-between-first-and-last-slide-of-a-carousel/60580084?noredirect=1#comment107179197_60580084)

```js
next_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  carousel_slide.style.transition = "all 0.3s ease-in-out";
    dot.forEach(e=>e.classList.remove( "active" ))
  counter++;
  carousel_slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-size * (counter + 1)}px)`;
  if (counter >= carousel_images.length) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      counter = 0;
      dot[counter].classList.add("active");
      carousel_slide.style.transition = "none";
      carousel_slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-size}px)`;
    }, 300);
  }else{
      dot[counter].classList.add("active");
  }
    
});

prev_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  carousel_slide.style.transition = "all 0.3s ease-in-out";
    dot.forEach(e=>e.classList.remove( "active" ))
  counter--;
  carousel_slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-size * (counter + 1)}px)`;
  if (counter < 0) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      counter = carousel_images.length - 1;
      dot[counter].classList.add("active");
      carousel_slide.style.transition = "none";
      carousel_slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-size * (counter + 1)}px)`;
    }, 300);
  }else{
      dot[counter].classList.add("active");
  }
});
```

Just modify that two click event listener will work perfectly the carousal I guess.

For clicking the dot you may use the below code

```js
dot.forEach(function(e, i){
    e.addEventListener("click", (elem)=>{        
        dot.forEach(e=>e.classList.remove( "active" ))
       counter=i; dot[counter].classList.add("active");
    carousel_slide.style.transform = `translateX(${-size * (counter + 1)}px)`;
    })
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577870/how-to-add-smooth-transition-between-first-and-last-slide-of-a-carousel/60580084?noredirect=1#comment107179197_60580084

Comment: Thank you. I think that smooth transition is gone between first and last slide and vice-versa. I asked above stated question to have this feature in slideshow. I don't want to lose it. Can you edit existing code and retain this feature.

Comment: oops! I think you just need to fix your carousal that's why I just focused on that. Anyway I will try to fix that too. I have just edited my answer with clicking the dot feature.

Comment: Good job, please check that transition one, it is the last thing I need to do

Comment: I guess you have found answer for your smooth transition, I can remove this part from my answer if you want.

Comment: Kindly edit the answer and add that transition, when I remove `counter--` or `counter++` from that block of code. The transition is gone.

Comment: Edited the answer, hope this will all works as expected. cheers :)